# Dell Latitude 7490 not detecting sim card

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, dell

I have dell latitude 7490 it comes with default sim slot in it.

In the connection manager / any where its not showing any kind option to connect and use sim card data..

The device it self is not detected.

```
Ubuntu Version :
root@nk:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
root@nk:~# 

root@nk:~# nmcli device show | grep "GENERAL.DEVICE:"
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s31f6
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
root@nk:~#
```

Comment: Start with checking BIOS options if built in modem is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this tread is older, but for others like myself whois researching this issue in 2022-2023, I had the same problem. I ran Diagnostics in BIOS setup & it stated that there was no LTE card installed. That didn't make sense to me as a SIM tray was present, and if present, that meant a broadband card should have been present. I ended up opening the bottom cover & discovered there really wasn't a card installed...BUT the antennas were present. (I bought this unit as Certified Renewed). I had to purchase this:

Dell DW5811e Snapdragon X7 LTE 3P10Y Sierra EM7455 Card 4G Qualcomm Module

You can find new 4G LTE broadband cards on eBay for about $25.

BUT...there are now 5G cards available:

Fibocom FM350-GL

They're pricey, but I found one on Ali Express for around $100. I haven't upgraded to it yet, but plan to in the future. Research more if this 5G card will work for your particular application.